# Extracting CRU precipitation data from netcdf into separate GeoTIFF files

Tags: cdo-climate

I would like to extract CRU precipitation data in netcdf format into separate GeoTIFF files. Usually if the netcdf file only have variables: `lon`, `lat`, `time` and `pre`
I can manage to extract it using below script:

```
for t in `cdo showdate input.nc`; do
  cdo seldate,$t input.nc dummy.nc
  gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_ullr <top_left_lon> <top_left_lat> <bottom_right_lon> <bottom_right_lat> -a_srs EPSG:4326 dummy.nc $t.tif
done
```

The CRU precipitation data have variables: `lon`, `lat`, `time`, `pre` and `stn`

I can't use above script because it contains 2 subdataset, got message from CDO: `Input file contains subdatasets. Please, select one of them for reading.`

How to select `pre` variables in CDO and applying into above script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that the files have more than one variable then you can select the variable "pre" using the command selvar, which you can then pipe to seldate:

```
cdo seldate,$t -selvar,pre input.nc dummy.nc
```

Comment: Thank you! It's worked. I will use your suggestion for next analysis. While ago before finding your way, I used ```cdo delname,stn input.nc output.nc```, deleting variable ```stn``` then execute using my script above, worked but not efficient :)